# Real examples of non-positive definite integrals

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, big-list

We need to get some examples of non-positive definite integrals in real practice (mathematical physics, engineering, mathematical statistics and etc).

Comment: What is a positive definite integral?

Comment: The definite integral is a number. This number can be positive and can be non-positive.

Comment: Are you just asking for an example of an integral that is nonpositive? Because in that case... $\int_{0}^{1}-dx$. I feel as though your question does not make much sense, or that you have the terminology mistaken.

Comment: I know it, but I want to see example of non-positive integrals in real practice, not in study examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A car travels along a straight line. At time $t$, the car is travelling
with velocity 
$$
v\left(t\right)=\sin t.
$$
Negative velocity means that it is travelling in the "left" direction
(i.e. from $1$ to $0$), while positive velocity means that it is
travelling in the "right" direction (i.e. from $0$ to $1$).
Let $r\left(t\right)$ be the position of the car at time $t$. Find
an expression for $r\left(t\right)$ given $r\left(0\right)=0$ (the
car is initially at position 0).
\begin{align*}
r\left(t\right)-r\left(0\right)=r\left(t\right) & =\int_{0}^{t}v\left(s\right)ds\\
 & =\int_{0}^{t}\sin sds\\
 & =1-\cos t.
\end{align*}

Notice that $\sin t$ takes on values from $-1$ to $+1$ (i.e. the integrand is not everywhere nonnegative), as per your request. Cars do not usually travel along lines, and the velocity function is strange, but less idealistic examples can similarly be produced.

Comment: Thank you, it's not bad example.